# background image border

Tags: html, css

Is there a css property to set a border around a background image? I've been searching for that but haven't found it, does it exist or am I left with needing to draw the line manually around my background images?

Comment: [Similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458596/apply-a-border-to-background-image)

Comment: Regarding question - No, there is no css property to set border to background-images.
However there are workarounds.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can be done by adding image in a div and than set the border of the div

```
<div style="border:1px solid red;float:left;">
   <div style="background:url("...");float:left;"></div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Without specific implementation details it's very difficult (if not impossible) to provide a solution that works in all cases. Here's a couple solutions with the constraints provided:

### Example 1 - Fixed Size

If you know the height and width of the background image you can do something like this:

```css
div.bg {
  background-image: url('http://www.google.com/images/logo_sm.gif');
  border: 5px solid #000;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"> </div>
```

Working example:  http://jsfiddle.net/WUHmw/

### Example 2 - Repeating Background Image

If the background image repeats, you can do something like this:

```css
div.bg {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/ikxbnvc.png') repeat;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
   <p>Here is some text to on top of the background image.</p>
</div>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/pLz52/

Comment: nice, i'll look at that later today. In the meantime, I just laid a div around my image with the border I wanted...

Comment: My answer makes more sense and is much cleaner :)

Comment: This doesn't set a border around the image (as the original question asked). This sets a border around the `<div>`. Here is your [jsfiddle modified to show the problems](http://jsfiddle.net/WUHmw/82/)

Comment: @tatlar yes, as is, it requires you to specify the height and width of the background image. Without specific implementation details it's very difficult (if not impossible) to provide a solution for this that works in all cases. Regardless, I updated my answer with another solution that works if the background image is repeating.

Comment: this may be old question, but tatiar noted what i noted... the accepted answer provided is not setting border around the background-image itself and therefore is misleading to other readers. it may offer a solution to the OP, but it should not be considered correctly answering the question itself.

Answer (score 5):

this can also be done using css drop-shadow
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow

```css
    
 .box {
     width:400px;
     height: 400px;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items:center;
     border: 1px solid red;
       .bgImg{
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background: url('http://i.imgur.com/ikxbnvc.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        background-position: center center;
        filter: drop-shadow(0 0 1px black);
    }
 }
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="bgImg"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wtesuqjz/

the browser support is not perfect