# Apply a border to background image

Tags: css

I have some divs, and they have their backgrounds set as images using this:

```
background:url(myimage.jpg);
```

Now what I'm looking to do is set a border on that image that is set to the background.

I don't want to set a border on the div as this does not give the desired result, it must be a border on the image.

Not sure if this is possible, is it?

Comment: What effect does this give that differs from setting a border on the div itself?

Comment: Open image photoshop, select all, stroke.

Comment: Difficult to say without your html & css but with background-image, background-clip, background-origin and background-size, I am sure what you are trying to acheive can happen. FYI, the background-color and background-image are rendered under the content area + padding + border.

Comment: @BoltClock some of the images are portrait, some are landscape. The divs must be set to a set width, and if I set a border on the div it looks odd because the div is wider than the image if it's a portrait image.

Comment: @Kevin Boucher - I know how to add a stroke to images, that is not a feasible option in this case.

Comment: If you looking to make an inner border then you can set the `div background color` and use `padding` with `max-height` and `max-width` for the images to fit the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do it precisely as you've mentioned.  Since the background image is styling, rather than content, no additional styling can be added to it.

The best option would be to create a different image file to serve the bolder border.

Answer (score 4):

You could try using multiple backgrounds, by setting your base bg image and a second one as a border.

```
#container {
background-image: url(Main-bg), url(Border-img.png); 
background-position: center center, left bottom; /* border bottom in this case */ 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer.